# Compare two times without regard to Date associated - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, time

I am trying to find the difference in time (without days/years/months) of two different days.

Example:

```
#ruby >1.9

time1 = Time.now - 1.day
time2 = Time.now
#code to make changes
#test:
time1 == time2 # TRUE
```

My solution:

```
time1 = time1.strftime("%H:%M").to_time
time2 = time2.strftime("%H:%M").to_time
#test
time1 == time2 #True
#passes
```

I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this? Maybe we could keep the Date the same as time1/time2?

Comment: I think your `"%h:%m"` may not do what you think it does, BTW.  You'll get something like "Jun:06".

Comment: @Larsenal correct. have edited: %H:%M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually want the following:

```
((time2 - time1) % (60 * 60 * 24)) == 0
```